# iText 7 : image field (button) without border nor background (transparent)

Tags: java, itext7

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/blob/develop/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part2/chapter08/Listing_08_06_ReplaceIcon.java) to set the value of a button icon with an image (PNG file).

It works fine except that I can't find how the image can be set without border nor background. I tried to play with the `setStrokeColor` and `setFillColor` without success.

Comment: What border and background do you mean? Am i right that the first arrow shows the border you want to remove and the second - the background you want to remove? https://imgur.com/a/WZ80XRV

Comment: Yes, exactly, to remove the border and to have a transparent background (no background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that particular example one can simply remove the code which is used for adding the background and the border:

```
            canvas.
                saveState().
                setStrokeColor(modelButton.getBorderColor()).
                setLineWidth(1).
                rectangle(0, 0, occupiedArea.getBBox().getWidth(), occupiedArea.getBBox().getHeight()).
                stroke().
                setFillColor(modelButton.buttonBackgroundColor).
                rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, occupiedArea.getBBox().getWidth() - 1, occupiedArea.getBBox().getHeight() - 1).
                fill().
                restoreState();
```

Please comment that line. I've also changed the used jpg image to a png one and that's what I've got as a result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, solved. I wonder if all this code is really needed to set an image to a push button? It looks very weird to create a new field (CustomButton), to remove the previous field and then add the new one. I expect iText to provide high level abstraction for something that I think is a "basic" use case.

Comment: It seems that the sample is a bit outdated indeed. Have you tried PdfButtonFormField#setImage ?

Comment: Brilliant! A single line to replace all of this code :) The last thing is that I tried to compare both methods (big piece of code and the single line) and it looks like the single line method resizes the image to the size of the button rectangle. Is there a way to avoid that? I'm thinking maybe about the possibility to resize the button before setting the image?

Comment: Well, you can play with the widget annotation fields. 

For example, form.getField("advertisement").getWidgets().get(0).setRectangle(new PdfArray(new Rectangle(100, 100, 400, 400)));

Comment: I tried to use that but it's not so simple. I think that I will simply ensure the image and the button are at the desired size.